# Refresh the control or reload form from button click event handler on other form

Tags: c#, winforms, refresh, reload, findcontrol

I have a `GridView` in Liste_Form and button in Close_Form.

How can I refresh the `Gridview` in Liste_Form, when i click the button on Close_Form?

Or reload the Liste_Form.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few ways this can be done. One way I might suggest is passing a delegate to the second form in the constructor:

```
Form2 myForm2 = new Form2(RefreshGrid); // assign to a Form2 local variable
```

...where in Form1 (the grid owner) you have defined the `RefreshGrid` method:

```
void RefreshGrid(){
   // perform grid refresh
}
```

...so that in `myForm2` you can execute the action when the button is clicked:

```
void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e){
   refreshAction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define event on Close_Form (of course consider better name for event):

```
public event EventHandler SomethingHappened;
```

Raise this event inside button click event handler:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (SomethingHappened != null)
        SomethingHappened(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Subscribe to this event on Liste_Form:

```
Close_Form closeForm = new Close_Form();
closeForm.SomethingHappened += Close_Form_SomethingHappened;
```

Refresh your list in this event handler:

```
private void Close_Form_SomethingHappened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // refresh GridView
}
```